# Почему JQ игнорирует отсутствие класса?

Tags: jquery

Вот такой маленький пример:

```js
  $(".clickbl").click(function(){
    $(this).css({"background": "yellow"})
  });
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#s1").removeClass("clickbl");
  });
```

```css
.square {width: 50px;height: 50px; background: blue; font-size: 3em; padding: 10px;}
.clickbl {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s1" class="clickbl square">1</div><br>
<div id="s2" class="clickbl square">2</div><br>
<div id="s3" class="clickbl square">3</div><br>
<button id="btn">fixate s1 color</button>
```

Событие click по элементу происходит по имени класса, но этот класс убран! А событие все равно происходит. 
Я догадываюсь, что дело в непростых взаимоотношениях JS c DOM, но что можно сделать, что бы не фигачить кучу **if**?

Comment: потому что сначала надо попробовать разобраться, что вообще в этом коде происходит. Вы по селектору навешиваете элементам обработчик. Привесили и он у них есть, вот у этих конкретных элементов. Какой там был селектор уже не важно. Обработчик висит на элементах. Если вы уберете класс обработчик от этого никуда не исчезнет. так что у вас тут два варианта. 1) вешать обработчик не на сами элементы, а на родителя через `.on`  2) удалять с элемента все обработчики, либо этот конкретный, поименовав его.

Comment: __>Какой там был селектор уже не важно. Обработчик висит на элементах.__
Да, спасибо, так и подумал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', ".clickbl", function(){
  $(this).css({"background": "yellow"})
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо

Comment: @OupireZein Пожалуйста. Успехов.